# How to select rows in a many-to-many relationship? (SQL)

Tags: sql, join, many-to-many

I have a Students table and a Courses table. 
They have a many to many relationship between them and the StudentCourses table is the intermediary. 
Now, I have a list of Course ids and want to select the Students that follow all Courses in my list.
How??

```
--CREATE TYPE CourseListType AS TABLE
--(
--  CourseID INT
--)

DECLARE
     @CourseList CourseListType

CREATE TABLE #Students
(
     ID INT
    ,Name CHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #Courses
(
     ID INT
    ,Name CHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #StudentCourses
(
     StudentID INT
    ,CourseID INT
)

INSERT INTO @CourseList (CourseID)
    VALUES
         (1) --English
        ,(2) --Math

INSERT INTO #Students (ID, Name)
VALUES
     (1, 'John')
    ,(2, 'Jane')
    ,(3, 'Donald')

INSERT INTO #Courses (ID, Name)
VALUES
     (1, 'English')
    ,(2, 'Math')
    ,(3, 'Geography')

INSERT INTO #StudentCourses (StudentID, CourseID)
VALUES
     (1, 1)
    ,(1, 2)
    ,(2, 1)
    ,(2, 2)
    ,(3, 1)
    ,(3, 3)
```

In this example, I only want the result to be John and Jane, because they both have the two courses in my CourseList. 
I dont want Donald, because he only has one of them.

Have tried this JOIN, construction, but it does not eliminate students that only have some of my desired courses.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    @CourseList CRL
    INNER JOIN #Courses CRS ON CRS.ID = CRL.CourseID
    INNER JOIN #StudentCourses STC ON STC.CourseID = CRS.ID
    INNER JOIN #Students STD ON STD.ID = STC.StudentID
```

Comment: Do a JOIN. Use the WHERE clause to pick only the desired Course ids.

Comment: Make it easy - and possible - to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You can chain the `JOIN`s to use many linked tables

Comment: One does not need to know constraints to query. Table meanings--what a row says when in a table in terms of column values--are necessary & sufficient. PS "related to all" or "related to every" involves "relational division". PS You have a classic ambiguity--if there are no classes, do you want all students or none? [mre] PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want students with all your required courses, you can use aggregation and `having`:

```
SELECT sc.StudentId 
FROM #StudentCourses sc JOIN
    @CourseList cl
    ON sc.CourseID = cl.id
GROUP BY sc.StudentId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sc.CourseId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @DcourseList);
```

If you want additional information about students, you can join in the `Students` table (or use a `IN` or a similar construct).

Note that this only needs the `StudentCourses` table.  It has the matching ids.  There is no need to join in the reference tables.